# How to get all data as it is available from SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, delphi, ado

I'm trying to get data from SQLSERVER using TADOQUERY linked to my database , using this request

```
declare @num_p varchar(9)
declare cur1 cursor for select do_piece from F_DOCENTETE where (DO_Piece like ('____00')or DO_Piece like ('____A0')or DO_Piece like ('____B0') 
or DO_Piece like ('____B0')or DO_Piece like ('____C0') OR DO_Piece like ('____D0')OR DO_Piece like ('____E0')OR DO_Piece like ('____F0')OR DO_Piece like ('____G0')
OR DO_Piece like ('____H0')OR DO_Piece like ('____I0')OR DO_Piece like ('____J0')OR DO_Piece like ('____K0')OR DO_Piece like ('____L0')OR DO_Piece like ('____M0')
OR DO_Piece like ('____N0')OR DO_Piece like ('____O0')OR DO_Piece like ('____P0')OR DO_Piece like ('____Q0')OR DO_Piece like ('____R0')OR DO_Piece like ('____S0')
OR DO_Piece like ('____T0')OR DO_Piece like ('____U0')OR DO_Piece like ('____V0')OR DO_Piece like ('____W0')OR DO_Piece like ('____X0')OR DO_Piece like ('____Y0')
OR DO_Piece like ('____Z0')OR DO_Piece like ('____D0'))and DO_Date between ('01/01/2018') and('31/12/2018') and do_type in ('16','17')
open cur1
fetch cur1 into @num_p 
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
select  f_docligne.do_piece,f_docligne.ct_num,F_COMPTET.CT_Intitule,AR_Ref, DL_Design,DL_Qte, DL_PrixUnitaire,DL_PUDevise,DL_Frais,DL_PUTTC, DL_MontantHT,
 DL_MontantTTC,DO_Ventile,DO_Cours,f_docligne.do_date from F_DOCLIGNE,F_DOCENTETE,F_COMPTET
 WHERE  f_docligne.DO_Piece=F_DOCENTETE.DO_Piece and F_DOCLIGNE.DO_Type=F_DOCENTETE.DO_Type and f_docligne.CT_Num=F_DOCENTETE.DO_Tiers 
 and F_DOCENTETE.DO_Tiers=F_COMPTET.CT_Num and f_docligne.DO_Piece like((select LEFT(@num_p,5))+'_') order by f_docligne.DO_Piece
fetch cur1 into @num_p 
end
close cur1
deallocate cur1
```

the problem is that in sqlserver i see all records while fetching 
but in delphi app it returns only last fetch , so how can i get it as SQLSERVER doest , shows data as it is displayed

Comment: Please show your Delphi code

Comment: Can you add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: `like '___[0,A-Z]0'`

Comment: I think you could do this in one select statement without using a cursor.

Comment: `but in delphi app` because your code is returning multiple resultsets and client-side code is not ready for this. The simplest workaround: put all records into temp table during cursor processing, perform single select from it in the end. Step 2 - rewrite without cursor, step 3 - normalize your data model.

Comment: the delphi code is simply an Adoquery that uses the above SQL request

Comment: @IvanStarostin how can rewrite it without a cursor ?

Comment: you could start by making your query much more readable by using the iso join syntax in stead of this deprecated join style. something like `inner join table1 t on ...`

Comment: Well,  you need an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), imo, because you are asking about your Delphi code and readers shouldn't have to guess exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

**This does not answers the question how to get your query as SQL Server does** , but you could retrieve your results by rewriting your query so you dont need a cursor.
Its hard to alter a query when little is known about the schema, but I tried anyway.
You should really use the newer join style, it is around for more than 20 years now and is much more readable.
Also use date formats that are region independant, like 'yyyyMMdd' for example.

This should get you started, but you need to fill in a lot of ??? off course

```
select  L.do_piece, L.ct_num, E.CT_Intitule, ???.AR_Ref, ???.DL_Design, ???.DL_Qte, ???.DL_PrixUnitaire, ???.DL_PUDevise, 
        ???.DL_Frais, ???.DL_PUTTC, ???DL_MontantHT, ???.DL_MontantTTC, ???.DO_Ventile, ???.DO_Cours, L.do_date 
from    F_DOCLIGNE L
  inner join F_DOCENTETE E on L.DO_Piece = E.DO_Piece
                          and L.DO_Type = E.DO_Type
                          and L.CT_Num = E.DO_Tiers
  inner join F_COMPTET P on E.DO_Tiers = P.CT_Num

where (E.DO_Piece like ('____00') or E.DO_Piece like ('____A0') or E.DO_Piece like ('____B0') 
       or E.DO_Piece like ('____B0') or E.DO_Piece like ('____C0') OR E.DO_Piece     like ('____D0') OR E.DO_Piece like ('____E0') OR E.DO_Piece like ('____F0') OR     E.DO_Piece like ('____G0')
       OR E.DO_Piece like ('____H0') OR E.DO_Piece like ('____I0') OR E.DO_Piece like ('____J0') OR E.DO_Piece like ('____K0') OR E.DO_Piece like ('____L0') OR E.DO_Piece like ('____M0')
       OR E.DO_Piece like ('____N0') OR E.DO_Piece like ('____O0') OR E.DO_Piece like ('____P0') OR E.DO_Piece like ('____Q0') OR E.DO_Piece like ('____R0') OR E.DO_Piece like ('____S0')
       OR E.DO_Piece like ('____T0') OR E.DO_Piece like ('____U0') OR E.DO_Piece like ('____V0') OR E.DO_Piece like ('____W0') OR E.DO_Piece like ('____X0') OR E.DO_Piece like ('____Y0')
       OR E.DO_Piece like ('____Z0') OR E.DO_Piece like ('____D0')
      )
and   E.DO_Date between ('20180101') and('20181231') 
and   E.do_type in ('16','17')

order by L.DO_Piece
```

or as suggested by @IvanStarostin you could do

```
select  L.do_piece, L.ct_num, E.CT_Intitule, ???.AR_Ref, ???.DL_Design, ???.DL_Qte, ???.DL_PrixUnitaire, ???.DL_PUDevise, 
        ???.DL_Frais, ???.DL_PUTTC, ???DL_MontantHT, ???.DL_MontantTTC, ???.DO_Ventile, ???.DO_Cours, L.do_date 
from    F_DOCLIGNE L
  inner join F_DOCENTETE E on L.DO_Piece = E.DO_Piece
                          and L.DO_Type = E.DO_Type
                          and L.CT_Num = E.DO_Tiers
  inner join F_COMPTET P on E.DO_Tiers = P.CT_Num

where E.DO_Piece like '___[0A-Z]0'
and   E.DO_Date between ('20180101') and('20181231') 
and   E.do_type in ('16','17')

order by L.DO_Piece
```

Comment: How does this explain what the OP was asking, namely why his Delphi app only retreives the last part of what SSMS does?

Comment: @MartynA well it does not, it offers another way to retrieve his data that only has one part

Comment: @MartynA And in the comments he did ask how to rewrite without using a cursor

Comment: Sorry, his question should in the q, not in a comment.  His q says "so how can i get it as SQLSERVER doest?"

Comment: @MartynA I added that in the answer

Comment: `E.DO_Piece like '___[0A-Z]0'`

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL statement returns multiple resultsets, so you need to get each resultset. 
I used next approach in old Delphi7 application and it worked for me. All you need is to call NextRecordset() method.

Delphi part:

```
procedure TForm1.btnOpenClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   s: string;
   rs: _RecordSet;
   n: Integer;
begin
   // Here, I assume that you have TADOQuery component already created,
   // with correct Connection or ConnectionString property.
   s := 'Your SQL statement';
   try
      if qry.Active then qry.Close;
      qry.SQL.Clear;
      qry.SQL.Add(s);
      qry.Open;
   except
      on E: Exception do begin
         ShowMessage('Error ' + E.Message);
         Exit;
      end{on};
   end{try};

   // Consume multiple resultsets
   rs := qry.Recordset;
   repeat
      while not rs.Eof do begin
         // Do what you want with fields values.
         // ShowMessage(rs.Fields['FieldName'].Value);
         rs.MoveNext;
      end{while};
      rs := qry.NextRecordset(n);
   until (rs = nil);

   //
   qry.Close;
   ShowMessage('OK');
end;
```

Comment: SQLServer gets recordsets while fetching , where qry.open waits till the whole request is completed

Comment: Imo your `repeat` loop should be a `while` one, otherwise it's an accoident waiting th happen.

Comment: @MartynA Sorry for delay and thanks for this comment. I use 'repeat' loop because of the nature of NextRecordSet() method (first call returns a dataset for the second set of records) and the type of the SQL statements (only SELECT). 
Of course this can be done with 'while', but it is interesting for me to know what are possible disadvantages of using 'repeat'.

Comment: I guess that If `rs` would be `nil` from the start, than the `repeat` will still force the code `while not rs.Eof do` to execute, and because `rs`is `nil` it will not end well

Comment: @GuidoG Yes, this is obvious (`repeat` works that way), but why `rs` would be `nil` after `qry.Open`? Is here something about ADO multiple resultsets, that I miss? Thanks.

Comment: Well the cursor could have no rows for example, so none of the querys has a resultset. I dont know what `rs` will be then I guess it could be `nil` then